# How to find text in a string using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried indexOf(), findText() and other few methods for finding a string pattern in a text in google app script. None of the above method works.

```
var str="task is completed";
```

I'm getting this string from google spreadsheet.

I just want to find whether the above string contains a string "task" .

Comment: task is present in the string with this condition-- if(str.indexOf("task")>-1){ }

Comment: I'm getting this error message : TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to check if the `str` is present:

```
if (str) {
    if (str.indexOf('task') > -1) {
        // Present
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `test` and `regex`:

```
/task/.test("task is completed");

/task/.test(str);
```

1. `/task/`: Regex to match the 'task'
2. `test`:   Test the string against regex and return boolean

Comment: this is overkill for what is being asked

Comment: well, it just added what was already present in an existing answer below.

Comment: @ZigMandel `I'm getting this error message : TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined.`

Answer (score 4):

a simple `str.indexOf("test")>=0`  does it. it works. not sure why you say it doesnt work as you havent shown any code to point out the problem.
if you want to check regardless of case use `str.toLowerCase().indexOf("test")`

Comment: `I tried indexOf(), findText() and other few methods for finding a string pattern in a text in google app script. None of the above method works.`

Comment: you are still not showing the code that doesnt work. update your question and include it

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make the array value a string so apps script doesn't think it's searching an array. Add double quote to your `toString()` function.

```js
var arr = ["blah", "blahYES", "NOblahYES"]

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].toString().indexOf("YES") > -1) { 
        // do something awesome. 
    }
}
```